# C++ Constructor error - Expected ')' before token '<'

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

What is wrong wit the following constructor declaration? I keep getting this error:

Expected ')' before token '<'

```
class Environment{
    public:
        Environment(vector<vector<char> > roomData);


     private:
         //....
};
```

Note: ok I see what's wrong. I did not add: using namespace std;

Comment: If you've seen the answer then add your own answer to the question and select it as the correct answer. Or select the answer below if it was correct.

Answer (score 12):

What's `vector`? If it is supposed to be `std::vector`, then did you include `<vector>`? And it is `std::vector`, not just `vector`, unless you have the corresponding using declaration or  directive somewhere higher in the code.